# Provide access among the users

Tags: 7, users

I need a requirement like this. In my site, there will be 2 types of user role.

1) Role A
2) Role B

Role A users can able to create the new users and assign them a Role B. I want to provide the access among the Role A users.

Let say **User 1** of **Role A** created **3** users of Role B and **User 2** of **Role A** created another **2** users of Role B.

I need to provide access to **Role A** users like the users who have been created by **User 1** of **Role A** cannot be accessible or editable for **User 2** of **Role A** and vice versa.

Is there any custom module to achieve this or we need to go for custom implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow exactly what you're asking, but if you want to give lower level users the ability to assign roles without needing the 'administer permissions' permission or other high level permissions, you can add the module [RoleAssign](https://www.drupal.org/project/roleassign).

> RoleAssign specifically allows site administrators to further delegate
>   the task of managing user's roles while withholding the Administer
>   permissions permission.
>
> RoleAssign introduces a new permission called Assign roles. Users with
>   this permission are able to assign selected roles to still other
>   users. Only users with the Administer permissions permission may
>   select which roles are available for assignment through this module.
>
> RoleAssign is ideal for smaller sites with a system administrator and
>   one assistant administrator role that should be reasonably restricted
>   in what it allows. For larger sites with multiple levels of
>   administrators or whenever you need finer-grained control over which
>   role can assign which other role, check out Role Delegation.